# C# Including reference dll within my project

Tags: c#, dll, .net-4.0

Referencing dll within my project is not too clear form me

1. When including `dll Reference` to my project does that mean that when moving the release `.exe` to another PCs will allow it to run ? or do I have to move the `dll Reference` too with my project ?
2. if Yes then what the best approche to do it ?

`dll Reference` is too ambiguous thinks im my mind please if someone can help me to understand it specifically the point above

thanks

Answer (score 2):

*When including dll Reference to my project does that mean that when moving the release .exe to another PCs will allow it to run ?*

No this was the old time but with .net one of the main goal was to avoid the [dll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell) hell

*or do I have to move the dll Reference too with my project ?*

yes you have to move all dll in your release folder after compiling was done

*if Yes then what the best approche to do it ?*

the best approach it depends on what you are targetting 
you can just zip the release folder and copy it to your target machine  I think it is the best one for you to get started